# UPenn CIS 194 Homework 1: Validating credit card numbers

Tags: haskell, homework, e-commerce, checksum

I am working through *UPenn CIS 194: Introduction to Haskell (Spring 2013)*. Since I am not able to take the course for real I am asking for CR (feedback) as it could be from teacher in that course.

**HW1** - Validating Credit Card Numbers - [Full description](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/hw/01-intro.pdf)

A shortened problem statement:

> Validate a credit card number by the following steps:
>
> 1. Double the value of every second digit from the right
> 2. Take the sum of the digits of the new values
> 3. Check whether the sum modulo 10 is 0.
>
> Write the functions `toDigits`, `toDigitsRev` and `doubleEveryOther` for the first task, `sumDigits` for the second, and `validate` for the third.

```hs
toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev 0 = []
toDigitsRev n
  | n < 0 = []
  | n < 10 = [n]
  | otherwise = n `mod` 10 : toDigitsRev (n `div` 10)

toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits n = reverse (toDigitsRev n)

doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther (x:[]) = [x]
doubleEveryOther (x:y:zx)
  | length (x:y:zx) `mod` 2 == 0 = 2*x : y : doubleEveryOther zx
  | otherwise = x : 2*y : doubleEveryOther zx

sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits [] = 0
sumDigits (x:[]) = x
sumDigits (x:xs)
  | x < 10 = x + sumDigits xs
  | otherwise = sumDigits (toDigits x) + sumDigits xs

validate :: Integer -> Bool
validate 0 = False
validate n = (sumDigits (doubleEveryOther (toDigits n))) `mod` 10 == 0

type Peg = String
type Move = (Peg, Peg)
hanoi :: Integer -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> [Move]
hanoi n a b c
  | n == 0 = []
  | n == 1 = (a, b) : hanoi 0 a b c
  | otherwise =  hanoi (n-1)  a c b ++ [(a, b)] ++  hanoi (n-1) c b a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## toDigitsRev

You can combine these two cases:

```
toDigitsRev 0 = []
toDigitsRev n
  | n < 0 = []
```

I think having one case makes the code clearer:

```
toDigitsRev
  | n <= 0 = []
```

## doubleEveryOther

You are correct to write `doubleEveryOther` as a recursive function, but ... you don't need to call `length` on every call!

Think of a way to writing `doubleEveryOther` but with calling `length` at most once.

## length and reverse

As you become more familiar with Haskell you learn that you should be wary of calling `length` and `reverse` on lists. In this case it is not a big deal because the lists involved are very short, but, in general, if you find yourself using these functions a lot it's an indication that you are using the wrong data structure.

As a bonus exercise, see if you can figure out a way to implement the `validate` function without using `length` or `reverse`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try to get rid of `length`

Comment: Updated `doubleEveryOther` is available at: [public gist file](https://gist.github.com/drets/60c2434b85d1dfb19006)

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track, I think.  If I had to pick one general criticism, it would be to watch out for redundant special cases.

In my opinion, the exercise guides you towards making an unnecessary complication in `toDigits` and `doubleEveryOther`.  Actually, the list of digits from right to left, as produced by `toDigitsRev`, is the more natural representation to work with.  If you work with the list in left-to-right order, then `doubleEveryOther` needs to look ahead to see whether the list has an odd or even digit count, which is awkward.  Therefore, if given free reign, I'd define a `doubleEveryOther'` that expects right-to-left input instead.

`toDigitsRev` does not need special cases for 0 and for `n < 10`.  Instead of calling `div` and `mod`, use the `divMod` function to capture both pieces of information from the same calculation.

```
toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev n
  | n <= 0    = []
  | otherwise = m : toDigitsRev d
  where
    (d, m) = n `divMod` 10
```

As mentioned above, we can simplify `doubleEveryOther` by working right-to-left:

```
-- Doubles the second, fourth, sixth… numbers in the list
doubleEveryOther' :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther' (x:y:zs) = x : 2 * y : doubleEveryOther' zs
doubleEveryOther' (x:[])   = [x]
doubleEveryOther' []       = []
```

You don't need a case for `sumDigits (x:[])` — it's already covered by `sumDigits (x:xs)`, where `xs` is the empty list.  The way you wrote it is fine, but personally I'd prefer to write it as `sum . map sumDigits'` so that you can see at a glance that it's performing a sum of some transformed values.

```
sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumDigits = sum . map sumDigits'
  where
    sumDigits' n
      | n < 10    = n
      | otherwise = sumDigits $ toDigitsRev n
```

The `validate` function does not need a special case for 0.  It's also more idiomatic to set up a "pipeline" of function calls using `$` than to use nested parentheses.

```
validate :: Integer -> Bool
validate n = 0 == (sumDigits $ doubleEveryOther' $ toDigitsRev n) `mod` 10
```